# Removing one-to-many relationshiop from schema

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

We currently have two large tables (table A has a one-to-many relationship with table B) in a MySQL database that we need to join between, and for performance reasons we would like to remove this join.

Is there a sensible way of taking the rows in table B and representing them in a column (or multiple columns) in table A? We’ve looked at using arrays of composite data types, but there doesn’t seem to be a good way to either index this data, or to efficiently query it.

We’re currently using MySQL, but are considering moving to Postgres. We will definitely consider any database that can solve this problem for us, though.

Comment: Have you tried to improve the performance by adding indexes?

Comment: What do you define as a "large" table?

Comment: Yes try adding indexes on join columns it will definitely improve performance. Also if the table is really large (say 3M - 5M+), you can consider using partitioning on some columns and then specify that columns in where condition of your join. Keep in mind always check explain output before finalising your join queries.

Comment: If you move to postgres: don't denormalise. A two-table setup has a smaller disk/buffer footprint, and (given sufficient foreign keys / indexes) will perform probably better.

Comment: About porting to postgres, mysql is definitely capable of solving these problems. You just need to spend some time with it.

Comment: Post the output of the explain statement. Run the following `EXPLAIN MY QUERY` and post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a intermediate *view*, it will speed up the process.

if [A]-1---n-[B], you can also set a foreign key to A into B, then AxB cartesian product no longer needed

Comment: MySql is not so good with views. The views are created on the fly, so the view query is executed each time in addition to your query on view.

Comment: Uday this is not always true. MySQL can create a view by either executing the query with a where clause or use a temp table. I have very high performance views in MySQL.

Comment: @Namphibian At the moment PostgreSQL does /not/ support system maintained materialized views (with temp tables as you describe) so if they're considering Pg that's out. Of course trigger-maintained materialized views work great in Pg, but are more hassle to build and maintain.

Comment: As a note though, PostgreSQL has *much* better view support than MySQL where it is not involving materialized views.  Basically a view is like an SQL macro which gets expanded into the query at run-time, so only one query is run.

Answer (score 0):

The option will be to fetch the related data in application layer. that is first fetch a row from table one and then in second query fetch the related rows from second table. Try to evaluate the performance of both codes. that is with a single query and with two queries.

Still, as mentioned in comments section. try adding indexes on join columns. try to use where condition to limit the data. and most importantly try to limit the result-set that is number of rows required as output. using limit will reduce the time required for getting additional rows.